# Here SDK Not Found on Flutter iOS

Tags: flutter, here-api, flutter-ios-build

We are attempting our first build on iOS using the Here Flutter SDK.  It appears that we followed the instructions, yet we receive a "here sdk not found" message.  Perhaps the documentation is not complete or there is a missing pre-requisite?  We are using the latest MacOS and version 2.0 of the Flutter SDK.  Other iOS builds on the same machine that do not use the Here SDK work fine.

Comment: We were able to more closely identify the issue.  The build works successfully in "release" builds, but not in "debug".  What's odd is that it simply fails to build.  It would be expected for a "release" build to suppress break points, but the debug build actually fails.

Comment: Hi, could you please let us know what was the error msg ? For this "HERE SDK not found" you wanna go to developer.here.com to download the SDK for flutter then unzip it and put it to the plugin under the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest MacOS then you may also run on a M1 chip. Try to follow the workaround as described [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.7.0.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#troubleshooting):

Exclude the `arm64` architecture for `Any iOS Simulator SDK` in the `Build Settings/Architectures/Excluded Architectures/Debug` setting within Xcode.

If this does not help, try to execute one of the example apps, for example: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/hello_map_app. If everything is set up correctly, you should be able to build for Android. Then you can hopefully narrow down the issue.

It is worth to mention that the latest release supports Flutter 2, but *not* yet FFI 1.0.